# Prolog code calculating factorial

Tags: prolog, factorial

I'm new to Prolog and I'm trying to write a piece of code that calculates factorial of a number.
This code works fine:

```
fact(0,1).
fact(N, R) :- N > 0, N1 is N - 1, fact(N1, R1), R is R1 * N.
```

But this one doesn't:

```
fact(0, 1).
fact(N, R) :- N > 0, fact(N - 1, R1), R is R1 * N.
```

Can someone please explain?

Comment: One could rewrite the second version of  `fact\2` to evaluate its first argument each time, and get around the problem in the second version, but it is more conventional to do as you have in the first version (evaluate before passing).  The flexibility of Prolog to manage "lazy evaluation" of arguments is potentially useful, but the factorial computation is too straightforward to take advantage of it.

Comment: A challenge would be to rewrite either version to be tail-recursive (eligible for last-call optimization).  Often one needs to introduce an extra argument (e.g. `fact/3`) to make this work.

Answer (score 4):

The issue is that prolog primarily uses **unification** to do computation. To get it to do arithmetic operations you need to tell it to do so explicitly using the `is` operator.

So, in your first program you explicitly tell it to perform subtraction with the clause `N1 is N - 1`, so that works as expected.

But in your second program you are not asking for arithmetic computation, but unification, when you wrote `fact(N - 1, R1)`.

If I had the fact `fact(5 - 1, foo).` defined, then I could query for `?- fact(N - 1, Y), write([N, Y]).` and prolog would happily unify `N` with `5` and `Y` with `foo`. This query would output `[5, foo]`.

So, to go one step further, if I had the fact `fact(foo - bar).` then the query `?- fact(X - Y), write([X, Y]).` would happily unify and return `[foo, bar]`. The `-` doesn't denote subtraction - it's part of the structure of the fact being represented.

Answer (score 2):

When passing around arithmetic expressions (instead of numbers), you need to **evaluate** expressions at certain times.

Arithmetic operators like `(>)/2` automatically do that, so the goal `1 > (0+0)` succeeds, just like `1 > 0` does.

Implicit unification (in clause heads) and explicit unification with `(=)/2` goals expresses equality of *arbitrary* Prolog terms, not just arithmetic expressions. So the goal `0 = 0` succeeds, but `0 = (1-1)` fails.

With arithmetic equality `(=:=)/2`, both `0 =:= 0` and `0 =:= (1-1)` succeed.

In your second definition of `fact/2`, you could make the first clause more general by writing `fact(N,1) :- N =:= 0.` instead of `fact(0,1).`. As an added bonus, you could then run queries like `?- fact(5+5,F).` :)